# Definir un valor por default a un double en mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tab_gas_card (
id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
vehicle_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
folio VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
nip VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
date date NOT NULL,
cost DOUBLE NOT NULL,
amount DOUBLE DEFAULT 0,
active BIT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
CONSTRAINT fk_gas_card_tab_vehicle_id FOREIGN KEY (vehicle_id) 
REFERENCES tab_vehicle (id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

y quiero que el campo amount tenga por default un valor inicial de 0, pero así tal cual como tengo mi código, solo me genera un NULL, como podría solucionar esto?

Answer (score 1):

Te faltaron las comillas, y agrégale comilla simple también al 0, de esta forma:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tab_gas_card` (
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`vehicle_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`folio` VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
`nip` VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
`date` date NOT NULL,
`cost` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
`amount` DOUBLE DEFAULT '0',
`active` BIT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
CONSTRAINT fk_gas_card_tab_vehicle_id FOREIGN KEY (`vehicle_id`) 
REFERENCES tab_vehicle (`id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

Comment: gracias Adríana he visto que eran 10 campos! =| haha, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

En ves de un DOUBLE intenta con un FLOAT y en su valor default agregale un '0.00', así:

```
amount FLOAT(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
```

Espero te sirva, saludos.

Comment: ya también lo intente de esa forma colega y no

Comment: gracias por tomarte el tiempo y tu ayuda

Comment: edite la respuesta, me parece que con float, definiendo la y usando como default '0.00' te funciona. saludos.